# How to extract plugin dll using query expression in dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I need to extract plugin dll using query expression. I know I can do it using database and can extract it from "PluginAssemblyBase" table and "content" column. Is there anyway I can extract it using query expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get 'content' attribute and use 'FromBase64String' method to get raw bytes.

```
String connectionString = @"AuthType=AD;Url=http://xyz/CRO; Domain=DEVDOMAIN; Username=user01; Password=12345";
CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
IOrganizationService orgService = conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
QueryExpression qExpr = new QueryExpression("pluginassembly") { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "pluginassemblyid", "content" }) };
qExpr.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "YourAssemblyName");
EntityCollection entColl = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(qExpr);
Byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String((String)entColl[0]["content"]);
```

Comment: is there any way to convert this byte data into readable source code in C#?

I wan to show the source code in a text file/ mutliline textbox

Comment: save it to file and use C# decompiler like ILSpy or JustDecompile

Comment: file would be txt extension file. 

Does these decompilers accept text file or just dlls?

Comment: they accept assemblies, it could be .dll, .exe or other, assemblies are not txt files